# How to return results of submitted form in a modal

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a contact form on contactpage1.php (department, name, email, message). When it is submitted the form 'action' is contactpage2.php which validates the data and either return error messages or emails the message.

Rather than having to go to contactpage2.php, I would prefer to keep everything on one page and have contactpage2.php open in a modal.

How would I do that?

So far, I've seen lots of example of clicking a button to open a modal with the contact form but that's not what I am after. Can I do it as described above?

I'm using Bootstrap modals elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Ajax is the solution

Comment: If not ajax, you can create a post back, generate the modal with the data, then manually trigger the modal with JavaScript.  Its the I cba-with-ajax workaround.

Comment: Wait, you say you want to open contactpage2.php in a Modal, yet *that's not what I am after*. Please clarify and maybe post the code you have tried.

Comment: Twisty: "So far, I've seen lots of example of clicking a button to open a modal with the contact form but that's not what I am after." (e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). What I want is to open the modal when I submit the form.

Comment: @TerryAlly, Here are the steps according to your question 1. you have form on contactpage1.php. 2. Submit it with Ajax 3.show modal in Ajax success function with `$('#selector').modal('show');` and can also bind the element in modal to show the message in modal, so what you need is Ajax Method and all other steps can be taken care inside Ajax call.

Comment: @Shehary ... yes that makes sense and I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571953/results-of-submited-form-in-a-modal/33576036#comment54923566_33571953) by [Shehary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4258081/shehary)

> Here are the steps according to your question
>
> 1. you have form on `contactpage1.php`.
> 2. Submit it with Ajax.
> 3. show modal in Ajax success function with `$('#selector').modal('show');`
>
> You can also bind the element in modal to show the message in modal,
>   so what you need is the Ajax Method and all other steps can be taken
>   care inside Ajax call.